# Override default window/system menu

Tags: windows, winforms, winapi

I want to add an "Always-On-Top"-menuentry to the system menu of all windows (the menu which opens when you right click the titlebar or click the icon). I'd prefer C# or C++, but if worst comes to worst I'll also use VB...

I know there are some applications like Dexpot which do this, but I was unable to find useful source code or free applications which do this for all windows and not just their own. 
I also know that there are other ways to achieve this functionality (AutoHotkeys or small programs which live in the system tray and let you select windows which should stay on top), but I'm looking for a more fluent and intuitive way. Ideally I'd add a small pin button to the titlebar, but my guess is that that's much more involved, so I'll stick with the menu variant for now.

Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: It's possible to use the `DllImport("user32.dll") SetMenuItemInfo` function. However, if you want a really customized menu you are probably better off subclassing `ToolStripDropDown` and disabling the default window menu. Then display the `ToolStripDropDown` instead of the default menu when the area of the titlebar is clicked.

Comment: _"I'd prefer C# or C++, but if worst comes to worst I'll also use VB..."_ - VB can do things that c++ can't?

Comment: [What if two programs did this?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/06/07/426294.aspx)

Comment: @IInspectable then you have more entries :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `AddMenuItems()` method and test using MS-Paint. One thing I noticed is that after the program is closed, the modified system menu becomes wonky. Possibly this is because the events are not coming from the process' UI thread. A possible work-around is in the `ApplicationExit` event to call `GetMenu(hMainWindowHandle, true)`, where true means revert the menu.

```
public static class AlwaysOnTop {

    static AlwaysOnTop() {
        Application.ApplicationExit += delegate {
            try {
                foreach (DictionaryEntry de in htThreads) {
                    Hook h = (Hook) de.Value;
                    RemoveMenu(h.hMenu, h.uniqueId, 0);
                    //DeleteMenu(h.hMenu, h.uniqueId, 0);
                    UnhookWinEvent(h.hWinEventHook);
                }
            } catch {
            }
        };
    }

    private const int EVENT_OBJECT_INVOKED = 0x8013;
    private const int OBJID_SYSMENU = -1;
    private const int WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT = 0;
    private const int MF_STRING = 0x00000000;
    private const int HWND_TOPMOST = -1;
    private const int HWND_NOTOPMOST = -2;
    private const int SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
    private const int SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
    private const uint MF_UNCHECKED = 0x00000000;
    private const uint MF_CHECKED = 0x00000008;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd, bool bRevert);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool AppendMenu(IntPtr hMenu, uint uFlags, uint uIDNewItem, String lpNewItem);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll",SetLastError=true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWinEventHook(uint eventMin, uint eventMax, IntPtr hmodWinEventProc, WinEventProc lpfnWinEventProc, uint idProcess, uint idThread, uint dwFlags);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern int UnhookWinEvent(IntPtr hWinEventHook);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
    private static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool CheckMenuItem(IntPtr hMenu, uint uIDCheckItem, uint uCheck);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool RemoveMenu(IntPtr hMenu, uint uPosition, uint uFlags);

    //[DllImport("user32.dll")]
    //private static extern bool DeleteMenu(IntPtr hMenu, uint uPosition, uint uFlags);

    private static Hashtable htThreads = new Hashtable();
    private static WinEventProc CallWinEventProc = new WinEventProc(EventCallback);
    private delegate void WinEventProc(IntPtr hWinEventHook, int iEvent, IntPtr hWnd, int idObject, int idChild, int dwEventThread, int dwmsEventTime);
    private static void EventCallback(IntPtr hWinEventHook, int iEvent, IntPtr hWnd, int idObject, int idChild, int dwEventThread, int dwmsEventTime) {
        //callback function, called when message is intercepted
        if (iEvent == EVENT_OBJECT_INVOKED) {
            if (idObject == OBJID_SYSMENU) {
                Hook h = (Hook) htThreads[(uint) dwEventThread];
                if (h != null && h.uniqueId == idChild) {
                    bool b = !h.Checked;
                    if (b)
                        SetWindowPos(h.hMainWindowHandle, (IntPtr) HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE);
                    else
                        SetWindowPos(h.hMainWindowHandle, (IntPtr) HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE);

                    CheckMenuItem(h.hMenu, h.uniqueId, (b ? MF_CHECKED : MF_UNCHECKED));
                    h.Checked = b;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class Hook {
        public uint uniqueId = 1001;
        public IntPtr hWinEventHook;
        public IntPtr hMenu;
        public IntPtr hMainWindowHandle;
        public bool Checked;
    }

    public static void AddMenuItems() {
        Process[] arr = Process.GetProcesses();
        foreach (Process p in arr) {
            if (p.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
                continue;

            if (p.ProcessName != "mspaint") // <-- remove or change this line
                continue;

            IntPtr hMenu = GetSystemMenu(p.MainWindowHandle, false);
            if (hMenu == IntPtr.Zero)
                continue;

            bool b = AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_STRING, 1001, "Always On Top");
            uint pid = 0;
            uint tid = GetWindowThreadProcessId(p.MainWindowHandle, out pid);

            Hook h = (Hook) htThreads[tid];
            if (h == null) {
                h = new Hook();
                h.hMenu = hMenu;
                h.hWinEventHook = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_OBJECT_INVOKED, EVENT_OBJECT_INVOKED, IntPtr.Zero, CallWinEventProc, pid, tid, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT);
                h.hMainWindowHandle = p.MainWindowHandle;
                htThreads[tid] = h;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't tested this yet, but it looks like a start from which I can work, so I'll accept it :) thanks!

Comment: Thanks. You might also consider using `SetWindowsHookEx` with the `WH_CALLWNDPROC` constant. There are a few threads that say that C++ is needed for it, i.e. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/318804 (Global Hooks at the bottom). I imagine the menu item functionality of DLL injection would persist, unlike the above C# code where the menu item's functionality depends on the application running (hence why it is removed on `Application.Exit`)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using a `ToolStripDropDown` instead of the default window menu. It can be made to look more like the default window menu by setting the background color, font and adding some icons if needed.

It was surprisingly more difficult to hide the default window menu. Maybe there is a better way. The failed attempts at hiding the menu are left in the code below. The default menu is still displayed when right clicking on the caption bar.

```
public class FormCustomMenu : Form {

    WindowMenu WindowMenu = new WindowMenu();

    public FormCustomMenu() {
        //this.ShowIcon = false;
    }

    private const int WM_INITMENU = 0x116;
    private const int WM_INITMENUPOPUP = 0x117;
    private const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x112;
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        if (m.Msg == WM_SYSCOMMAND) { //WM_INITMENU || m.Msg == WM_INITMENUPOPUP) {}
            Point pt = Cursor.Position;
            int h = SystemInformation.CaptionHeight;
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle(this.Location, new Size(h, h));
            if (!r.Contains(pt) || Cursor.Current != Cursors.Default)
                base.WndProc(ref m);
            else {
                Rectangle r2 = RectangleToScreen(this.ClientRectangle);
                WindowMenu.Show(r2.Location);
            }
        }
        else {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }

/*
    Failed attempts at hiding the default window menu.

    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        //IntPtr hMenu = GetSystemMenu(Handle, false);
        //SendMessage(hMenu, WM_SETREDRAW, (IntPtr) 0, (IntPtr) 0);
        //int count = GetMenuItemCount(hMenu);
        //for (int i = count - 1; i >= 3; i--)
        //  RemoveMenu(hMenu, (uint) i, MF_BYPOSITION);
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int GetMenuItemCount(IntPtr hMenu);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool RemoveMenu(IntPtr hMenu, uint uPosition, uint uFlags);

    //[DllImport("user32.dll")]
    //public static extern IntPtr DestroyMenu(IntPtr hMenu);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd, bool bRevert);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool DeleteMenu(IntPtr hMenu, uint uPosition, uint uFlags);

    private const int MF_BYPOSITION = 0x00000400; 
    private const int WM_SETREDRAW = 11;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 wMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);


    // this also removes the min/max/close buttons:
    //private const int WS_SYSMENU = 0x80000;
    //protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
    //  get {
    //      var p = base.CreateParams;
    //      p.Style = p.Style & ~WS_SYSMENU;
    //      return p;
    //  }
    //}
    */
}

public class WindowMenu : ToolStripDropDown {
    public WindowMenu() {
        Items.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem("Custom1"));
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you missed the *"all windows"* caveat in the question; i.e. how to add this to *all windows in the system*.

Comment: That part is obvious. Create a common Form class and have all your other forms subclass that Form. Or create an extension method that uses the `IMessageFilter` interface prefilter the `WM_SYSCOMMAND` message.

Comment: No I think you're still missing the point. Not all forms belonging to your program, all windows belonging to all programs. E.g. if Microsoft Word were running, its system menu would have the "Always on Top" menu item in it.

Comment: I'll post another answer since that requires a different approach.